# Google Drive details now showing up in powershell

Tags: powershell

I am new to powershell and to trying to run the basic query below on remote workstations.

```
Invoke-command -ComputerName comp1, comp2, comp3 -ScriptBlock {Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_logicaldisk}
```

However when I try to get the details of the G:\ (which is the Google File Stream Drive), only the drive letter comes up (please see screenshot). I ran the script with elevated credentials and still get the same result. If I run the script locally the details of the drive show up, however it's not working when I run on remote machines.

I really appreciate your help.

screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Probably visible to the specific user? That would explain why it works locally but not remotely. Are you running the remote command as the logged on user?